# Android : Unable to set TableLayout properly as wanted

Tags: android, width, scrollbar, android-tablelayout

I am showing data from DB in an Activity. I want a Table and buttons on bottom. For data thought TableLayout would be best option for it. I added TableLayout to HorizontalView & to ScrollView making it scroll vertically & Horizontally. Am adding all rows dynamically - including header. This part is working fine.

I want is when the contents is less than the screen width, it should yet occupy the whole screen width. For eg. If a table fits well in Portrait mode then ofcourse for Landscape mode their will be blank space left on the right. I don't want that space to eb empty, instead to occupy by all columns. If the row width is greater than the screen width then no issues at all - as horiontal scrollbar appears.

I tried few variations, but nothing helped out. Any idea what settings to make to utlize all space (if at all avbl) & show it.

And yes, 1 more issue of horizontal scrollbar, it appears just on the last row. I want it to 
appear below last row - so the border of last row is visible. My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" > 

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/browseTable" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="#FF0000" android:stretchColumns="1,2,3">

</TableLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal"  android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
    <Button android:id="@+id/browseAddBtn" android:text="Add" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/browseViewBtn" android:text="Edit" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"  />
    <Button android:id="@+id/browseReturnBtn" android:text="Return" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" />        
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

OUTPUT : 
[image]

Comment: capture a image of this, and add it here, and then tell what exactly you want.. it will help other to help you. :) thanks

Comment: @AnkitA, have added an image t oshow what I have and explaining what I want. Hope it will help others help me.

Comment: try my answer not all but yes your some problem will solve by that. second if you want to show float value. try to show till some length. like 4 places after decimal..

Comment: @AnkitA, REG show float value : I didn't get your point I mean how to do it ? I just get the value, convert it toString() and set the data in TextView : obj.getValue(field).toString()

Comment: you can do it like  obj.getValue(field).toString().substring(0,7),, something like that or you can get index of '.' and  can say substring.(0,str.indexof(",")+4) like dat

Comment: @AnkitA, Nope no success with float. I tried str.substring(0, str.indexOf(".")+2), that gives me just "1.0" & rowData.getValue(2).toString() gives "1.0E8". Actual entered value is "99999999.99". I even tried retrieving the float value in double. But that also didn't do any good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found one thing while solving your problem, about **TableLayout** when used inside a **HorizontalScrollView**. The **android:stretchColumns** is not working when we use Table Layout inside Horizontal Scroll View. So that you are getting blank space when screen is rotated or columns have less width data.

I hope you understand this. I am trying to solve this problem by replacing Horizontal Scroll View with some other. I will post answer if i get solution. Bye.

**EDIT**

Hi **Tvd** finally I got the solution for your problem. make below changes to your XML layout file.

In `<HorizontalScrollView>`

use

```
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
```

Use `stretchColumns = "*"` in **TableLayout** if you want all columns to be stretched.

Bye.  :-)

Comment: OH @Yugandhar Babu, wow excellent. fillViewPort did the work. Had asked this Q earlier also, but no proper response that works out. Your tip helped me out. I highly appreciate your helpline. Thanks a lot. You don't know this was in my ToDo list since I guess 20+ days. Had tried several things, but didn't get the desired results. Thanks once again.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes. some of your problem will solve by below layout code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/browseTable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#FF0000" >
        </TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/browseAddBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/browseViewBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Edit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/browseReturnBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Return" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I added the change layout_weight in ScrollView, but that didn't helped me. It didn't result in any changes to the output.

Comment: I liked your "ButtonBar" style idea. I wanted that also to put in bottom only, but wasn't getting a way for the same. You style idea did the trick. Thanks for ButtonBar style idea.

Comment: try fill parent for horizontal Scroll view and let me is it helping you. <HorizontalScrollView          android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: This also doesn't do any good. With this layout_width of Linear, Scroll, Horizontal & Table is "fill_parent". The TableLayout.LayoutParams for TableRow is also "Fill_parent" for Width.   TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams = 
     new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: I also tried adding stretchcolumns="1, 2, 3" to tableLayout, but that also didn't work.  android:stretchColumns="1, 2, 3"

Comment: i will try it myself,, after leaving office.. :) and let u know

Comment: i could not get time.. will update you soon.. join me on gmail. ankitawasthi1@gmail.com