# Android: Scrollbars to appear below the component instead of on the component

Tags: android, scrollbar, tablelayout, horizontal-scrolling

I have a table to which I have added a vertical & horizontal scrollbars. The horizontal scrollbars appears on the bottom on the last row of the table. Due to this the border of the table isn't visible. I want it to appear below the last row of the table. I tried adding margins, but nothing worked. Same is with vertical scrolling too. This is my xml :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" android:layout_weight="1">

    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" > 

        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/browseTable" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#FF0000" android:stretchColumns="1,2,3">
        </TableLayout>    
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is the result :
[image]

Any helpline is highly appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i understood what you are looking for. I tried and got solution by using image view inside Scroll and Horizontal Scroll views, its working fine. It may or may not work with your Table Layout, test it.

Add below line in your **Table Layout** in XML file.

```
android:padding="5dip"
```

Let me know is it working or not.

Comment: I tried scrollbars = none with Table & scrollBarStyle with HorizontalScroll, but none worked with me too.

Comment: Yes it does. But I did scrollbars = none to TableLayout, yet the HorizontalScroll will show up. So, it has to show. And making all as "none" makes no sense at all.

Comment: If I make scrollbars =none in scrollview & horizontal view, then how will I see the scroollbars. And then what's the use & sense of using them. I think, you didn't get my question properly.

Comment: yes that did the work. I had tried with margin but missed out padding to use with TableLayout :(. Padding did the trick. I just made it paddingBottom instead of padding all around.  Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome. I took vertical scroll bars into consideration, so that i added padding to all, also to limit no.of statements for both bottom and right padding.

Comment: @YugandharBabu & Deepthi Jabili, can you help me with this problem also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968895/android-unable-to-set-tablelayout-properly-as-wanted   Its regarding TableLayout and its width. Am stuck on it since long. Can't find any proper help. Pls check if you could helps.