# Table Layout setStretchAllColumns(true) inside HorizontalScrollView does not work in Lollipop

Tags: android

I have a table layout which I placed inside a HorizontalScrollView, as the number of edittext inside each row of table is dynamic, I am programmitically putting them. The following codes work perfectly fine in version 9 (Pie) ( and also probably in Oreo Go ) but does not work in Lollipop. The xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mrinp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="Number"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="submit"
    android:onClick="generate"
    />
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tbl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText edr;
TableLayout tl;
LinearLayout myLayout;
int M;
int layoutWidth;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edr = findViewById(R.id.mrinp);
    tl = findViewById(R.id.tbl);
    tl.setStretchAllColumns(true);

    tl.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color._light_green));

}

public void generate(View view) {
    tl.removeAllViews();

    M = Integer.parseInt(edr.getText().toString());
    int setWidth;


    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cold));

        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {

            if(i==0){
                tl.setColumnStretchable(j, true);
                }

            EditText ed = new EditText(this);
            ed.setMinWidth(70);
            tr.addView(ed, j);
        }

        tl.addView(tr);
    }

}

}
```

Note that any one of `android:stretchColumns="*"` or `tl.setStretchAllColumns(true);` or `tl.setColumnStretchable(j, true);` works as desired in Pie. Here is the snapshot.

[image]

But the above code does not work (none of those three I mentioned) in Lollipop.
Here is the snapshot.

[image]

Note that if I replace HorizontalScrollView with LinearLayout in Lollipop it works fine.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9126103/5370550)

Add `android:fillViewport="true"`

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:fillViewport="true">
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tbl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: if solution works for you then accept answer so it might help to others.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, as you mentioned earlier this do look like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968895answer   answered by Yugandhar Babu, I upvoted that also.